# How to optimize Sparql query that timed out

Tags: sparql

Do you have any hints to deal with this query which timeout :

```
SELECT distinct ?person ?personLabel ?personDescription ?dateOfBirth
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5;  # Type d'entité : être humain
          wdt:P569 ?dateOfBirth;
           wdt:P27 ?country. #Pays de citoyenneté
  ?politician wdt:P106 wd:Q82955.  # Profession : homme politique
  ?person ?relation ?politician.
  OPTIONAL {?person  wdt:P569 ?dateOfBirth.}
  ?country wdt:P17  wd:Q142.  # France -> ?country wdt:P30  wd:Q15. pour Afrique 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?person wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}  # Filtre pour exclure les personnes avec une date de fin
  Filter(YEAR(?dateOfBirth)>1940)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
limit 10
```

Efit: @unanswered there is some difference between the é approaches (with country or not)
[image]

Comment: why `?country wdt:P17  wd:Q142.` ? I mean, why are you not using the ID of France directly for the citizenship of the person??

Comment: and why another `OPTIONAL {?person  wdt:P569 ?dateOfBirth.}` if you already get the birthdate it in the beginning of the query without an OPTIONAL?

Comment: Thanks for your answer: i tried diretcly with 
           wdt:P27 wd:Q142. #Pays de citoyenneté France
 but it it didn't return anything. And i am a beginner in Sparql, if you have any suggestion for the same query it could help me!

Comment: starting from `SELECT distinct 
?person 
?dateOfBirth
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5;  # Type d'entité : être humain
           wdt:P27 wd:Q142. #Pays de citoyenneté
  ?person wdt:P569 ?dateOfBirth;
  # hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true .
  Filter(?dateOfBirth >= "1941-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime)
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?person wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o}} LIMIT 10` I'd suggest. It returns people of France born at or after 1941-01-01 and still being alive

Comment: You didn't mention what your query is supposed to return, so I omitted the `politician` relationship for now. If you want to say "somehow related to another person being a politician`, just append the corresponding triple patterns of your initial query